# Bialgebra pairing on ring polynomial $K[x]$

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups

I need your help on how to show the existence of a bialgebra pairing: for the polynomial ring $k[x]$ over a field $k$, there is a bialgebra pairing $t:k[x]\otimes k[x]→k$ such that $t(x,x)=1$. What is the unique bialgebra pairing satisfying $t(x,x)=1$?

Comment: What is $P(K[x])$?

Comment: &P(K[x])$ is the Space of primitive elements.

Comment: When you write $x \in P(K[x])$, do you mean two different things by the same letter $x$, one on the right hand side and the other one the left hand side?

Comment: I guess that $K$ is a field, but what is $k$? Is $K$ an extension field of $k$, perhaps?

Comment: Sorry it is typo it is all the same field $k$  through out. For example let $U=k[x]$ with the Hopf algebra structure determined by $x \in P(U)$. I mean the space $P(U)$ gives the coalgebra structure on the polynomial ring.

Comment: There are plenty of bilinear maps $t:U\otimes U \to k$ that satisfy $t(x,x)=1$ and are not bialgebra pairings. For example on a basis, $t(x^n,x^m)=1 if m=n=1$, and zero otherwise. The point is that there exists a (unique) pairing $t$ which is a bialgebra pairing and fulfills $t(x,x)=1$. I want to know how to define the pairing.

Comment: However, to avoid confusion the primitive property is not needed here.

Comment: Your $t$, if exists, is uniquely determined by $t(1,x)=t(x,1)=\varepsilon(x)$, $t(x,x^2)=t(\Delta(x),x\otimes x)$, $t(x^2,x)=t(x\otimes x,\Delta(x))$, $t(x,x^3)=t(\Delta(x),x\otimes x^2)=t(\Delta(x),x^2\otimes x)$, etc. You just have to check whether what you obtain in this way is consistent or not.

Answer (score 4):

1. The bialgebra pairing condition implies $(1,b_1b_2)=(\Delta(1),b_1\otimes b_2)=(1,b_1)(1,b_2)$, so in particular $(1,1)=(1,1)^2$, and $(1,1)$ is zero or one. Also by a similar calculation, $(b_1b_2,1)=(b_1,1)(b_2,1)$.
2. We have $$(x,1)=(x,1\cdot1)=(\Delta(x),1\otimes 1)=(x\otimes 1+1\otimes x,1\otimes1)=(x,1)(1,1)+(1,x)(1,1).$$ If $(1,1)=0$ this implies that $(x,1)=0$, and if $(1,1)=1$, this implies that $(1,x)=0$. Together with a similar evaluation of $(1,x)$ this means that $(x,1)=(1,x)=0$. Since $(1,b_1b_2)=(1,b_1)(1,b_2)$ and $(b_1b_2,1)=(b_1,1)(b_2,1)$, we have $(1,x^n)=(x^n,1)=0$ for $n>0$.
3. We have 
   $$
   1=(x,x)=(x,x\cdot 1)=(\Delta(x),x\otimes 1)=(x\otimes 1+1\otimes x,x\otimes 1)=(x,x)(1,1)+(1,x)(x,1)=(1,1),
    $$
   so $(1,1)=1$.
4. Clearly, we have 
   $$
   (x^m,x^n)=(\Delta(x^m),x\cdot x^{n-1})=\left(\sum_{j=0}^m\binom{m}{j}x^j\otimes x^{m-j},x\otimes x^{n-1}\right).
    $$
5. Let us show by induction that $(x^m,x^n)=0$ for $k\ne n$. We already know it for $(m,n)=(0,1),(1,0)$. Suppose it is established for $m+n<N$, where $N\ge 2$. Let us consider $m+n=N$. We may assume $m,n>0$ since $(1,x^k)=(x^k,1)=0$. By the formula above we have
   $$
   (x^m,x^n)=\sum_{j=0}^m\binom{m}{j}(x^j\otimes x^{m-j},x\otimes x^{n-1})=\sum_{j=0}^m\binom{m}{j}(x^j,x)(x^{m-j},x^{n-1}).
    $$
   If $j=0$ or $j=m$, we have $(x^j,x)(x^{m-j},x^{n-1})=0$ since $(1,x^k)=(x^k,1)=0$. Suppose that $0<j<m$. In this case $j+1<m+n$, hence if $j\ne 1$ we have $(x^j,x)=0$ by induction, and if $j=1$, we have $(x^{m-1},x^{n-1})=0$ by induction as $m-1+n-1<m+n$.
6. Finally, by the same formula for $m=n$
   $$
   (x^n,x^n)=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}(x^j\otimes x^{m-j},x\otimes x^{n-1})=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}(x^j,x)(x^{n-j},x^{n-1}),
    $$
   and by the result we just proved only $j=1$ has a non-zero contribution,
   so 
   $$
   (x^n,x^n)=n(x^{n-1},x^{n-1}),
    $$
   which immediately gives 
   $$
   (x^n,x^n)=n!
    $$

Comment: The answer is perfect for the previous version of the question. Note that now it is not presumed anymore that $x$ is primitive.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე : I assume that the author of the question means the standard bialgebra structure on the polynomial ring when writing "the polynomial ring". I still think that "the primitive property is not needed here" means that the original version of the question was overloaded by unnecessary notation, not that $x$ is not assumed primitive.

Comment: Thanks. That's really helpful. Also can I use the primitive properties to say that $t$ is non-degenerate if char $k=0$?.

Comment: @UmarMuhammadFaruq this calculation does indeed show that the pairing is nondegenerate in char 0. It assumes the "standard" bialgebra structure on $k[x]$ for which $x$ is a primitive element, and nothing else.

Comment: Good. If you don't mind I will also like to know what if $char k = p>0$ because It seems from the compuatation above that $ker(t)=x^p$, right? thanks.

Comment: @UmarMuhammadFaruq If the ground field is of characteristic $p$, then the kernel of the pairing is the *ideal* generated by $x^p$, since $n!$ is divisible by $p$ for all $n\ge p$.